# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while inserting data into room database

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

I am trying to download data from firebase firestore and insert it into the room DB for some offline use and avoid time-lag using the MVVM architecture pattern but when I do that I get an `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` error I am inserting the data into the room DB inside a coroutine.

My code

```
class HomeFragmentViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private var mDatabase: AppDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(application)!!
    private val postListRoom: MutableList<PostRoomEntity> = mutableListOf()
    private val postList: LiveData<MutableList<PostRoomEntity>>? = getPostList2()

    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    private val db: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    private val myTAG: String = "MyTag"

    @JvmName("getPostList")
    fun getPostList(): LiveData<MutableList<PostRoomEntity>>? {
        return postList
    }

    @JvmName("getPostList2")
    fun getPostList2(): LiveData<MutableList<PostRoomEntity>>? {
        var postsDao: PostsDao? = null
        Log.d(myTAG, "postDao getPost is " + postsDao?.getPosts())
        return mDatabase.postsDao()?.getPosts()
//        return postList
    }


    fun loadDataPost() {

        val list2 = mutableListOf<PostRoomEntity>()
        db.collection("Posts")
            .addSnapshotListener { snapshots, e ->
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w(myTAG, "listen:error", e)
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }

                for (dc in snapshots!!.documentChanges) {
                    when (dc.type) {

                        DocumentChange.Type.ADDED -> {
                            dc.document.toObject(PostRoomEntity::class.java).let {
                                list2.add(it)
                            }
                            postListRoom.addAll(list2)
                            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                                mDatabase.postsDao()?.insertPost(postListRoom)
                            }

//                            mDatabase.let { saveDataRoom(postListRoom, it) }
                        }
                        DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED -> {

                        }
                        DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED -> {
                            Log.d(myTAG, "Removed city: ${dc.document.data}")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    }

}
```

> PostsDao

```
@Dao
interface PostsDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertPost(PostEntity: MutableList<PostRoomEntity>)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAllPosts(PostEntity :List<PostRoomEntity>)


    @Query("Select * from PostRoomEntity")
    fun getPosts(): LiveData<MutableList<PostRoomEntity>>

//    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id= :id")
//    open fun getNoteById(id: Int): NoteEntity?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very error-prone to use MutableLists with asynchronous tasks or to expose them to outside functions. You are doing both, and this can result in them being modified from two different places in code simultaneously, which can cause a ConcurrentModificationException.

You should use read-only Lists to eliminate this risk. For example, use `var`s of type `List` instead of `val`s of type MutableList.

Some other issues with your code:

- You are adding the whole contents of the list to the main list on each step of iteration, so the last item is added once, the second-to-last item is added twice, and so on. You are also inserting that whole exploded list in your local database on each step of iteration, so it is even more exponentially multiplied with redundancies. If you are just trying to update your local database with changes, you should only be inserting a single row at a time anyway.
- Unnecessary nullability used in a few places. There's no reason for the DAO or your LiveData to ever be null.
- Unnecessary intermediate variables that serve no purpose. Like you create a variable `var postsDao: PostsDao? = null` and log the null value and never use it.
- Redundant and non-idiomatic getters for properties you could expose as public directly.
- Redundant backing property for the value that's already held in a LiveData.
- You can make your DAO functions `suspend` so you don't have to worry about which dispatchers you're using to call them.
- There's no reason for the DAO to have an insert overload for a MutableList instead of a List. I think the parameter should just be a single item.
- You can have a single coroutine iterate the list of changes instead of launching separate coroutines to handle each individual change.

I also recommend not mixing Hungarian and non-Hungarian member names. Actually I don't recommend using Hungarian naming at all, but it's a matter of preference.

And it's a little confusing that you have two databases, but there is nothing about their names to distinguish them.

Fixing these problems, your code will look like this, but there might be other issues because I can't test it or see what it's hooked up to. Also, I don't use Firebase, but I feel like there must be a more robust way of keeping your local database in sync with Firestore than trying to make individual changes with a listener.

```
class HomeFragmentViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val localDatabase: AppDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(application)!!
    private val mutablePostList = MutableLiveData<List<PostRoomEntity>>()
    val postList: LiveData<List<PostRoomEntity>> = mutablePostList

    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    private val firestore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    private val myTAG: String = "MyTag"

    fun loadDataPost() {

        db.collection("Posts")
            .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w(myTAG, "listen:error", e)
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }

                mutablePostList.value = snapshot!!.documents.map {
                    it.toObject(PostRoomEntity::class.java)
                }

                viewModelScope.launch {
                    for (dc in snapshot!!.documentChanges) {
                        when (dc.type) {
                            DocumentChange.Type.ADDED -> {
                                val newPost = dc.document.toObject(PostRoomEntity::class.java)
                                localDatabase.postsDao().insertPost(newPost)
                            }
                            DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED -> {

                            }
                            DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED -> {
                                Log.d(myTAG, "Removed city: ${dc.document.data}")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    saveDataRoom(postListRoom, localDatabase) // don't know what this does
                }
            }

    }

}
```

```
@Dao
interface PostsDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertPost(postEntity: PostRoomEntity)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertAllPosts(postEntity: List<PostRoomEntity>)

    @Query("Select * from PostRoomEntity")
    fun getPosts(): LiveData<MutableList<PostRoomEntity>>

//    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id= :id")
//    open fun getNoteById(id: Int): NoteEntity?
}
```